# create view that draws data from a schema?

Tags: sql, view, schema

I'm having trouble understanding what this question is asking, and then how to also write this view.

**Here are the instructions:**
Create a view named CUSTOMER_NEW_UNIQUE that pools the data in the CUSTOMER_NEW table in the PGURUJI schema.  List each customer only once.  Do NOT include CustomerID in your view. Note: you cannot assume the data in the CUSTOMER_NEW table is clean, unique, or in the same format as what is in your table! So be careful. State your assumptions very clearly as to how you define the same customer. Query this view to validate it

Customer_New is in the schema for Parag’s username, but I'm not sure I understand what that means or how to use that information to change the code that I have so far, which is:

```
CREATE VIEW Customer_New_Unique AS
    SELECT UNIQUE *
    FROM customer_new;
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data from `customer_new` table.

Comment: so here's the thing, I'm not sure how to access that or where to. I was told it's in the schema for Parag's username but I don't know what that means or where to find it

Comment: Without the base table `customer_new` sample, there is no way to solve this problem because there are so many possibilities